# How does sklearn GridsearchCV in combination with pipeline work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I've some trouble understanding how the GridsearchCV really works, in combination with a self-defined transformation.

What I want to achieve:
I want to implement a Transformer/Estimator, which allows switching between some methods depending on a parameter because I want to include these different methods inside the gridsearch.

Example: I have a self-defined Transformer called Scaler(), which either chooses MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler. (just for simplicity)

```
class Scaling():

    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.method=None
        self.params = {}
        print("INITIATING CLASS")


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X): 
        print("TRANSFORMING", X)
        if self.method == "minMax":
            self.scaler = 
            MinMaxScaler(feature_range=self.params["feature_range"])
        elif self.method == "std":
            self.scaler = StandardScaler()

        return self.scaler.fit_transform(X)

    def get_params(self, **params):
        return {**StandardScaler().get_params(), **MinMaxScaler().get_params(), 
                **{"method":""} }

    def set_params(self, **params):
        print("SETTING PARAMETER")
        self.method = params["method"]
        self.params = params
```

This is my example data:

```
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).reshape(-1,1)
y = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

My pipeline:

```
p = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', Scaling()),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])
```

My paramgrid and Gridsearch

```
hyperparams = {
    'scaler__feature_range' : [(0,1), (-100,10)],
    'scaler__method': ["minMax"]
 }

clf = GridSearchCV(p, hyperparams, cv=2)
clf.fit(data, y)
```

It actually works, but I'm really confused about the printing logs:

```
INITIATING CLASS
INITIATING CLASS
INITIATING CLASS
SETTING PARAMETER
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
INITIATING CLASS 
SETTING PARAMETER
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
INITIATING CLASS
SETTING PARAMETER
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
INITIATING CLASS
SETTING PARAMETER
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
TRANSFORMING [[ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
TRANSFORMING [[1][2][3][4][5]]
INITIATING CLASS
SETTING PARAMETER
TRANSFORMING [[ 1][ 2 [ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9][10]]
```

I have set cv=2. I would expect it like this.

1. Instantiate all the Transformers
2. set the parameters according to the Gridsearch
3. pass the train-fold through the pipeline
4. pass the test-fold through the pipeline
5. repeat
   So I would have expected 8 calls to the transformer method because we need one for the train and one for the test fold. Because of cv=2, we do this 2 times and because we are defining two different values for feature_range inside the paramgrid, we have to multiply it with 2, therefore 8. What's wrong?

But why are there so many calls of my Scaling class?
How can this order of logs be explained?
Why is the full sequence at the end transformed?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 groups of three transforms and the final single transform.

The groups are train pass, test pass and calculating training scores. The latter can be eliminated by `return_train_score=False` param in `GridSearchCV()` constructor.

The final transform is fitting the best performing model on the entire dataset. It can be eliminated with `refit=False` option to `GridSearchCV()` constructor.

So once you instantiate your clf object as:

`clf = GridSearchCV(p,hyperparams, cv=2, refit=False, return_train_score=False)`

you'll get 8 transforms as you correctly expected.

See a comment in GridSearchCV doc page:

> *return_train_score* : boolean, optional
>       If False, the cv_results_ attribute will not include training scores.
>       Current default is 'warn', which behaves as True in addition to raising
>   a warning when a training score is looked up. That default
>   will be changed to False in 0.21. Computing training scores is used to
>   get insights on how different parameter settings impact the
>   overfitting/underfitting trade-off. However computing the scores on
>   the training set can be computationally expensive and is not strictly
>   required to select the parameters that yield the best generalization
>   performance.

Comment: Is there a better way than mine if i want e.g. to have a function which controls which feature selection method is selected and how their parameters should look like?

Comment: For hyper-parameter optimization you could also look at `hyperopt` that's more feature-reach than a plain grid search. As for transformer selection, you are looking into AutoML field, so might want to look at how this is done. But look at hyperopt, it might allow you construct a pipe using parameters. I have recently use Ray Tune, it could definitely allow you to create your pipe inside a single experiment.